# IF ELSE logical condition statement does not work

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
  df1
  1. AB-CD-XY 
  2. AC-BE-DF-GH
```

I want to strip from the last hyphen to get something like this:

```
 1. AB-CD
 2. AC-BE-DF
```

This is my code

```
library(stringr)
ifelse(str_count(df1,'-')==3, 
   df_strip<- sub("^([^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*).*", "\\1",df1),
   df_strip<- sub("^([^-]*-[^-]*).*", "\\1", df1)
   )
```

At the moment i get the result below which shows that only the else part of my code works. the `sub` codes works separately on their own but not in the ifelse statement.

```
1. AB-CD
2. AC-BE
```

Comment: You can use `sub("-[^-]*$", "", df1[,1])`

Comment: Is `df1` a data.frame or a vector? Please see [how to create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for better ways to include data in your question that can be copy/pasted into R. Also, `ifelse()` is a vectorized function. You should not be doing assignment within the function itself, you should assign the result.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use "`<-`" inside `ifelse`

```
df1 <- c('AB-CD-XY', 'AC-BE-DF-GH')
df1_strip <- ifelse(stringr::str_count(df1,'-')==3, 
   sub("^([^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*).*", "\\1",df1),
   sub("^([^-]*-[^-]*).*", "\\1", df1)
)

df1_strip

[1] "AB-CD"    "AC-BE-DF"
```

Also note, df1 is not a data frame here.

Comment: You are welcome. I also refer to MrFlick's comment for ways how you can improve your possible future questions.